# Locationmanager didEnterRegion not called after ios11.4 upgrade

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocationmanager, geofencing, ios11.4

I am facing a strange issue. My app was calling `didEnterRegion` method earlier and after upgrading to my iOS 11.4 this method is never getting called, although the other delegate methods of Locationmanager are getting called.

I have Privacy - Location Always Usage Description ,Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description and Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description there keys are already there in my plist.

Comment: I have done Always share location permission on my app

Comment: CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() check this and you will get to know the service available or not